# Drupal adding a custom header per node

Tags: templates, drupal-7, drupal-themes

I have created the templeate **html-landing.tpl.php** and try to include it in a template with the following in my template.php`enter code here`

function myfuntion_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {

$node = menu_get_object();

if ($node->nid == 60) {

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html-landing';
```

}
}

The code is called but the template used is the standard html.tpl.php.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using underscore instead of dash?

I'd go for something like this:

```
function myfunction_preprocess_html(&$variables, $hook) {
  $node = menu_get_object();
  if ($node && $node->nid == 60) {
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'html_landing';
  }
}
```

More details at http://drupal.org/node/190815#comment-4167060